# What is the Concrete class in java

Tags: java

According to [this](https://www.quora.com/What-is-a-concrete-class-in-Java) document, and many similar documents, a concrete class is described as:

> A concrete class in Java is any such class which has implementation of all of its inherited members either from interface or abstract class

And can used like this:

```
public abstract class A {
 public abstract void methodA();
}

interface B {
 public void printB();
}

public class C extends A implements B {
   public void methodA() {
        System.out.print("I am abstract implementation");
    }

  public void printB() {
       System.out.print("I am interface implementation");
   }
}
```

In the above example class C is a concrete class.

Is this the only way to create a concrete class. Can you give me more info about concrete class?

Comment: A concrete class can be instantiated with the `new` keyword .

Comment: The question is somewhat unclear to me. If that is the question, you can also make a concrete class without it extending or implementing anything. Maybe putting it the other way round is more clear to you: Any class that is not abstract is concrete (Interfaces never are).

Comment: Thank you all about your feedback.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

A concrete class is a class that has an implementation for all of its methods that were inherited from abstract or implemented via interfaces. It also does not define any abstract methods of its own. This means that an instance of the class can be created/allocated with the **new** keyword without having to implement any methods first. Therefore it can be inferred that any class that is not an abstract class or interface is a concrete class.

In your code above, C will be a concrete class as it implements all abstract methods inherited from A and implemented from B. Also, it does not define any abstract methods of its own.

Comment: Thank you mdewit. This good.Can you give me the example please.

Comment: You saying If we can create instance that class is concrete. Am I  correct

Comment: Actually, @Dev4Wotld, it's the other way around: if it's a concrete class then one can instantiate it. Yes, it's symmetrical, but it's​ easier to think about this way.

Comment: Thank you Lew Bloch.Can you tell me what did you mean "but it's​ easier to think about this way". Is that about mdewit

Comment: @Lew Bloch are you suggesting that there are class types that can be instantiated that *aren't* concrete? Rewording it is making a different point, please clarify

Comment: @ChrisFarr. no. Of course not. And it's the same point looked at from the other end. You can look like you instantiate an interface: `new Interf(){...}`, but you're actually instantiating a concrete class. The complete statement is "A type can be instantiated iff it is a concrete class."

Comment: @mdewit The abstract class can also be declared so without any abstract methods being declared within the class, e.g. `public abstract class Abstract { public static void main(String[] args) { System.out.println("Abstract"); } }` or any methods at all, e.g. `public abstract class AnotherAbstract {}`. The answer by @LewBloch also covers these cases. I'd add that while the abstract classes cannot be instantiated, they can be initialized (so the first example [can be the initial class for the JVM](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21967340), `java Abstract`).

Answer (score 12):

The simplest definition of a concrete class is that it's a class that is not [abstract](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_(computer_programming)#Abstract_and_concrete).

Answer (score 3):

As per name suggests, concrete means Solid, it means having no any row part or unimplemented things(methods).So we can conclude that concrete classes are those classes that can be instantiated with new key word. 
  MyClass myClass = new MyClass();

Answer (score 2):

1.concrete class is a class which can never become 
an abstract or interface .It can extend or implement or both.
2.The class is said to be concrete if all its methods and variables has defined.

Answer (score 1):

A concrete class in Java is any such class which has implementation of all of its inherited members either from interface or abstract class

Answer (score 1):

In the above program, representing abstract as public class will sometimes show some compile time errors to define that in its own file. As simple, just avoid using public keyword or modifier while using abstract class in your program to avoid some uncertainty. Any method that is invoked using new keyword (object creation) other than abstract and interface classes is called as concrete class.